# Advanced documentation for node.js developer

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation

Recently our team is working on a new project with node.js. It is not difficult to start working with node.js. But now we're all just start to use this new technique and have little experience in such event-based development.

So I am wondering if there are any books, blogs or other materials covering the topics of "best practice" of node.js, just like "effective c++", "effective java", etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, i can just support you with the findings that helped me the most when learning "how to node":

- [DailyJS](http://dailyjs.com/): JavaScript in general, contains a lot of node.js specific posts/tutorials
- [HowToNode](http://howtonode.org/): Blog specifically about node.js, highly recommended
- [Essential JS Design Patterns](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/): REALLY good description of design pattern implementations in JavaScript
- [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/): great documentation about the most quirky parts of JavaScript

There are also some good books on advanced JavaScript techniques around, i haven't read them all in full though.

- [High Performance Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X) (by Nicholas C. Zakas)
- [Pro JavaScript Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059908X) (by Ross Harmes & Dustin Diaz)
- [Secrets of a JavaScript Ninja](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398869X) (by John Resig, to be released end of August 2011)

And last but not least, i recommend [GitHub](https://github.com/) as a source of learning. By digging through the source of some more sophisticated projects (such as [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express), [mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose) or [socket.io](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node)), you can learn A LOT about writing clean and proper node.js code.

Comment: nodenerd.net is not a node-related blog anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding JavaScript I would recommend to watch Douglas Crockfors's [videos](http://yuiblog.com/crockford/) and reading [resources](http://javascript.crockford.com/) on his website. Also [JavaScript Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806767) by Stoyan Stefanov is a very good book to read (even for experienced JavaScripters).

For node.js there is a [Node Tuts](http://nodetuts.com/index.html) website which contains video tutorials and there are also two node.js specific books which you can read now: [Mastering Node](http://visionmedia.github.com/masteringnode/) (open source eBook) and [Up and Running with Node.js](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449398583/index.html) (preview).

Answer (score 2):

CREATE A WEB APP WITH NODE.JS:
http://boldr.net/create-a-web-app-with-node

Real time online activity monitor example with node.js and WebSocket:
http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket

Answer (score 1):

**awesome link for MEAN stack and node , Angular , Mongodb.**
https://www.reddit.com/r/meanstack/comments/2v68zd/mean_js/

https://www.airpair.com/javascript/complete-expressjs-nodejs-mongodb-crud-skeleton

http://www.hacksparrow.com/the-mongodb-tutorial.html
http://webapplog.com/pro-express-js-master-express-js-the-node-js-framework-for-your-web-development-is-out/

http://azat.co/
https://www.udemy.com/mongoose/?couponCode=wal

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/nodejs-restify-mongodb-mongoose

http://www.javabeat.net/nodejs-mongodb/

http://webapplog.com/intro-to-oauth-with-node-js-oauth-1-0/

http://www.scoop.it/t/node-js-by-piyas-de
http://rapidprototypingwithjs.com/?utm_source=azat.co#section-sample

angular 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/26b237/introduction-to-angularjs-day-5/

http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/interactive-background/index.html

http://www.nodebeginner.org/

https://github.com/sergtitov/NodeJS-Learning

http://howtonode.org/