# Need to convert my php app in node.js

Tags: php, node.js, express

I need to change my app's platform from php/apache to node.js , but I am not understanding  how to go ahead.
My app is having structure like codeigniter.
I want to use express , I have read it's official ste , also beginner's tutorial.No problem with code but not understanding how to fit in it's structure.
Please assist me with some nice links or example

Comment: This is how to not port an application.

Comment: why you want to dump php

Comment: No hard feelings with php , its my first love but my superiors want to give node.js a try....

Comment: Then you probably need to learn how to build an application in node.js, and then with that understanding port it. Not sure whether we can give any other advice... although there may be guides on how to port a "classical" MVC app to node.js's model. Maybe worth Googling

Comment: Yes @Pekka keep Googling. The best way to learn a new language is to have to build something new in it. It's only those that are scared of making a mistake that care about paradigms. Paradigms are a dime a dozen in computer science land, and they are all good for a purpose. Usually for making large scalable applications.  The thing is most apps start small and bosses want a fast turn around. So get it done dirty, then polish it up when people care enough to put more money and man power behind it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't even remotely compare node.js to something like PHP. Node.js was designed to provide a full-stack high-performance IO framework, not a scripting language based on a web-server of your choice.

First of all, you HAVE to make sure you fully understand the node.js paradigm and it's event-based architecture. It's completely different to something like ASP.NET or PHP, you really have to rethink on the whole programming model. In order to achieve this, it's important to learn node.js FROM SCRATCH! Don't start directly with some framework like express or flatiron. Learn it from the basics: `console.log('Hello world')`

Maybe some good starting points:

- http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/
- http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/04/6-free-e-books-on-nodejs.php

Some further links:
[Advanced documentation for node.js developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400533/advanced-documentation-for-node-js-developer/5401560#5401560)

Comment: This. The OP's superiors may not know what they're getting into and how hard it is going to be to switch an existing application from the PHP world...

Comment: I know my friend , but instead of arguing I can make to learn node.js.It will be better addition in my resume only.. ;-)

Comment: ... and then the book "Node.js for PHP Developers - Porting PHP to Node.js" came from Oreilly, although it misses the whole paradigm etc thing mentioned in this answer

Comment: As a now reformed PHP dev I used Javascript event handling all the time, for all those things PHP couldn't do so well.  So Node.js is not such a paradigm shift at all. I'm happy I can now code in the same language for both client and server. Once you get your head around Promises it gets even better!

Answer (score 10):

I don't agree that you should roll your own before utilizing some of the excellent libraries available in node.js. No one recommends that you build your own MVC framework before using Ruby on Rails or ASP.NET MVC. However you definitely **must** understand the strengths and weaknesses of node.js and how to effectively leverage them.

ASP.NET and PHP are **much** more forgiving platforms than node.js. If you do something stupid  in most platforms, you can still deploy and have a functional system. They are very tolerant of poor performance and sloppy code. If you screw something up in node.js, it's possible for the entire webserver to simply stop responding to requests while it processes something.

It is possible to get extremely good performance and scalability from node.js, but you have to understand functional programming and make sure that the code you write doesn't block. You have to know how to break medium and larger applications up into separate parts (dare I say *nodes*?) that know how to communicate in order to accomplish more complex tasks.

Comment: I'm not talking about rolling your own framework, i just suggest that one has to learn node.js from the ground up before even attempting to write a basic web application :)

Comment: I disagree @schaemu you only need to understand some javascript and HTTP requests and headers to build a Node Express application. I know because I did it, and I never completed a single 'Hello Word' app. I just looked at examples. I've also done it in JSP, Symfony and Rails and I prefer Node over all of them. If the OP's bosses are realistic about the time required, there's no reason the OP can't achieve this.