# Is there any way to run Node.js in a <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, require

I would like to run Node.js in my webpage, the same way that you would with PHP or ASP.NET.

The reason for this is I would like to use require()'d modules from NPM in my browser javascript, however vanilla JS doesn't seem to support this. Is there any way I can run Node.js in my  tags? If not, would requiring examplenodefile.js in my browser javascript work?

Edit: Is there any alternative to this, if it isn't possible? I know I can set `script src` but that doesn't really work as nicely as `var foo = require('bar');`

Comment: No, there is not. You cannot run PHP or .net on the client side either.

Comment: node.js runs on the server, not the client.

Comment: Of course, many of the modules from npm work in the browser as well, you might have to use a module bundler that supports commonjs `require` though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript require() on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168451/javascript-require-on-client-side)

Comment: You need to tell us what your end goal is. Building websites with node (express) requires you to use templates and the like, and switching to that from PHP can be challenging. Plus, you obviously won't be able to run arbitrary node code in a browser environment anyway, given the restrictions on, say, file access and the like. Is this about a specific module? Or just about having to trouble to wrap your head around templating?

Comment: webpack is a nice bundler, but another nice option is systemjs,  https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs  here you don't need to bundle at all, it just makes your browser able to handle commonJs / ES / & AMD loaders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your above question I am assuming you want to use NPM modules in your browser side JavaScript. This is possible to do assuming you have web pack. You can use webpack to bundle the NPM packages inside a bundle file.

Check out webpack...

https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Just a simple way to use NPM modules in my websites. I'll accept when it lets me, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It can take some time to set up but when you set it up its a very powerful tool. Happy reading!

Comment: Again, many npm modules will not work in a client environment at all, webpack or not.

Comment: I use quite a bit of npm packages in my bundles. I haven't ran into to many that don't work unless they were built strictly for server side use, like an  http server or a server side templating engine.

Comment: @MicahBell Sure, but I suspect OP *does* want to do server-side stuff right in his `<script>` tags, given that he referenced PHP and ASP.NET.

Comment: @ChrisG  PHP / ASP.NET don't work inside a script tag either, they just render, just the same as if you were using Node / express.

Comment: @Keith I'm fully aware of that, thanks. I'm explaining to Micah that his solution will most likely lead OP down a blind alley, because OP is trying to do something that does not work at all but phrased it in a misleading way.

Comment: @ChrisG  So what was your point here -> `but I suspect OP does want to do server-side stuff right in his script tag`, and then mention PHP / ASP as if they did do server stuff right inside the script tag..?

Comment: @Keith If OP wants to run only npm modules suitable for client-side, Micah's solution is fine and exactly what OP is looking for. However I believe, based on OP mentioning PHP etc., that OP is trying to use "node-only" / server-side modules right in the browser, in which case webpack will help nothing. My point was to "warn" Micah that he's misleading OP because he's too optimistic about OP's understanding of node vs. client-side.

Comment: @ChrisG  I think the OP just wants the ability to use npm packages in his client side script. I am basing this of a statement he made, "The reason for this is I would like to use require()'d modules from NPM in my browser javascript, ".  Webpack has this capability, so I suggested it to him. I could be wrong about what he wanted. Maybe we will get more feedback from the OP.

Comment: @MicahBell Not to be rude or anything, but I'm aware of your assessment. It's why you posted the above answer. My assessment is different, mostly because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601868/node-js-loading-html-in-a-similar-way-to-php)

Comment: @ChrisG I understand what you are saying.  I don't think its rude. You are skeptical of whether or not the OP understands the technologies or not. The OP didn't ask me to critique his understanding of PHP or NodeJs. I probably wouldn't of answered if that was the case.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more appropriate if it explained the limitations for webpack (e.g. lots of NPM modules you cannot use in a browser because you can only use modules that will run in a browser - you aren't running node.js in a browser at all).