# How to run NodeJS in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Is it possible to run a nodejs file and use functions FROM that nodejs file from an html file? Or, is there a NPM Package that allows you to manipulate html elements in an html file from a nodejs file?

Comment: As in RCP or actually calling the client side's node binary? Or maybe you mean webpack? You need to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure, I want to be able to use nodejs inside an html file, but I haven't found any answers to it. I do have a nodejs file that loads the html file, although, I want to be able to control nodejs with the html file aswell. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually for your second question there is a package just for that. It's called Cheerio. Here's an example using it:

```js
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs'); 

fs.readFile('path/to/file.html', 'utf8', function(err, data) {

    if (err) throw err;

    var $ = cheerio.load(data);

    $('body').append('<p>Hello World</p>');
    console.log($.html());
});
```

Comment: No problem! I had a similar problem like this before. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Question: would it be able to add nodejs scripts? so like, a <script> tag that contains nodejs code like fs.readFile()?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708715/is-there-any-way-to-run-node-js-in-a-script-tag It has alot of helpful answers